# SQl Query to calculate Total in HH:MM Format

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table(production) which is having a column with name TimeSpent, the datatype of this column is varchar and it stores data in HH:MM format example 10:23,14:59,11:00 etc.I want to write a query in sql which will sum this and give me a total in HH:MM Format only.
I tried some thing like this but getting error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.':-

```
select CAST
(
(SUM (datepart(hh, convert (varchar, timespent, 108))) +
(sum(datepart(mi, convert (varchar, timespent, 108)))/60) ) AS VARCHAR(2)
)
+ ':' +
CAST
(
sum(datepart(mi, convert (varchar, timespent, 108))) - 60 * (sum(datepart(mi, convert (varchar, timespent, 108)))/60)
 as VARCHAR(2)) from production
```

Comment: Are you converting a varchar column into a varchar column with the style code for HH:MM:SS? If timespent is already a var char then surely you need to convert it to a date time before using the datepart function.

Comment: Yes i m doing same as you told, TimeSpent is varchar.

Comment: My query is working now, Just by decreasing the size of timespent to 25. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query worked for me, I had just updated my table and decreased the size of TimeSpent to Varchar(25) from varchar(60) and it is fixed.

```
select CAST
(
(SUM (datepart(hh, convert (varchar, timespent, 108))) +
(sum(datepart(mi, convert (varchar, timespent, 108)))/60) ) AS VARCHAR(2)
)
+ ':' +
CAST
(
sum(datepart(mi, convert (varchar, timespent, 108))) - 60 * (sum(datepart(mi, convert (varchar, timespent, 108)))/60)
 as VARCHAR(2))from production
```